# Pygame - Trying to Toggle a BOOL when a key is pressed, not while pressed

Tags: python, boolean, toggle, pygame

I'm trying to make BOOL toggle when a key is pressed not while since that just makes it toggle off and on (true and false) each frame if the key is held down.

Here's my little toggle code

```
if key[pygame.K_z] and robsHouse.pressed == False:
        robsHouse.pressed = True
    elif key[pygame.K_z] and robsHouse.pressed == True:
        robsHouse.pressed = False
```

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: is the elif actually nested in the if statement, or is that just an error when you copied your code? because if the elif is inside the if, then that would cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to toggle on `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` events.

Comment: He doesn't _need_ to toggle on `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP`.  That is only one way of doing this.  The `pygame.key` module allows for retrieving an array of boolean values (1 for each possible key).  This method is not typically encouraged, as you will miss very quick keystrokes which occur between frames, but some applications may not require knowledge of the event's occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

So, this Boolean will change when ever a button is pressed, correct?
Just use the `KEYUP` event and reverse the variable:

```
if event == KEYUP:
    if event.key == DESIRED_KEY:
        boolVar = not boolVar
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is toggling `robsHouse.pressed` every frame while you hold the key down is because the `key[pygame.K_z]` condition will be satisfied on each loop iteration while the key is held down, and then the secondary conditions will cause each other to be satisfied on alternating frames.

Without changing the way you are retrieving key data, you could do something like this:

```
if key[pygame.K_z]:
    robsHouse.pressed = True
else:
    robsHouse.pressed = False
```

Another way is to find `KEYUP` and `KEYDOWN` events from pygame's event module, rather than getting key data from the key module.  That could be done like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_z:
            robsHouse.pressed = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_z:
            robsHouse.pressed = False
```

Personally, I prefer the second approach in most cases.  You are going to need to process events from pygame's event module anyway, otherwise the queue will fill up and your program will become unresponsive (this is mentioned in the pygame event module documentation).